# Events with variable from outer block

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm working on the following function whose job is to restore state the expansion state to a kendo grid. As you can see the function can be called many times. A variable is populated, in this case 'expanded', in the outer block which is then used by an anonymous function that is assigned to an event that is used within.

When this function is called multiple time, will the variable 'expanded' be overwritten each time causing all instances of the anonymous function to use the last value given to 'expanded'? Or does run of 'saveExpansion' keeps its own instance?

```
function saveExpansions(gridname) {
    var grid = $("#"+gridname).data("kendoGrid");
    var expanded = $.map(grid.tbody.children(":has(> .k-hierarchy-cell .k-i-collapse)"), function (row) {
          return $(row).data("uid");
    });

    // Re-expand (might need to switch to a better event rather than waiting)
    grid.one("dataBound", function () {
      rowsToExpand = grid.tbody.children().filter(function (idx, row) {
         return $.inArray($(row).data("uid"), expanded) >= 0;
     });
     grid.expandRow(rowsToExpand);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each invocation of `saveExpansions()` will have its own instance of expanded.

You can see more about function closures [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp)